# jquery tooltip showing taking json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, pie-chart, jquery-tooltip

here is my jquery tooltip code.

```
var $tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip top in'><div class='tooltip-inner'></div></div>").hide().appendTo('body');
                var previousPoint = null;
                placeholder.on('plothover', function (event, pos, item) {
                    if (item) {

                        if (previousPoint != item.seriesIndex) {
                            previousPoint = item.seriesIndex;
                            var tip = item.series['label']+":" +item.series['percent'] + '%';
                            //var tip = item.series['Alert1']+":"+item.series['percent']+'%';
                            $tooltip.show().children(0).text(tip);
                        }
                        $tooltip.css({ top: pos.pageY + 10, left: pos.pageX + 10 });
                    } else {
                        $tooltip.hide();
                        previousPoint = null;
                    }

                });
```

And my Json Data :

```
[
    {
        "label": "FDR Compliance",
        "Assessments": "151",
        "Conductedon": "101",
        "OpenTasks": "141",
        "charts": [
            {
                "label":"Low",
                "data": "60",
        "Alert1":"90 Day",
        "Alert2":"Key Member",
                "color":"#68BC31"
            },
            {
                "label":"High",
                "data": "30",
        "Alert1":"Missed",
        "Alert2":"YTD",
                "color": "#DA5430"

            },
            {
                "label":"Medium",
                "data": "15",
        "Alert1":"E & OE",
        "Alert2":"Failure",
                "color": "#FEE074"

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the above code if in jQuery the tool will display the data if it is:

```
var tip = item.series['label']+":" +item.series['percent'] + '%';
```

In the tooltip the value displays correctly.

I want to display the `Alert1` value and not label value so when I write this code:

```
var tip = item.series['Alert1']+":"+item.series['percent']+'%';
```

in the tooltip the value says `"undefined"`

Help me out!!!

Comment: have a break miss suma :P

Comment: Provide jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The error is in accessing the JSON data and has nothing to do with tooltip. First learn how to take value from a JSON file.